# Why is the verb in plural?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Why is the noun *company* here followed by the verb in plural? Does this actually mean - *one of the companies*, and is it how it should always be written ?

> "... to use the services of a web hosting company who charge a fee..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

American English usually sees *company* as a singular collective noun, and thus uses a singular verb. This flavor of English also tends not to use the personal *who*, but the impersonal  *that* or *which* — in fact, [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-it-a-company-who-or-a-company-that) insists on it.

British English regularly sees *company* as an aggregate of individuals, thus with a plural verb:

> We can book a drug test for you with a local [*company who charge*](https://nz.indeed.com/Pay-Charge-jobs) $60 … indeed.com – New Zealand
>
> If you do go for full insurance, don't buy it through the car hire [*company who charge*](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2018/may/24/europcar-hire-car-damage-no-evidence) £12 a day or more … — *Guardian*, 24 May 2018.
>
> All services related to your power connection and your meters are handled by your distribution [*company who charge*](https://www.powershop.com.au/blog/powershop-and-fees/) us regardless of whether you're a new or existing customer. — Powershop.com.au, 7 Sept. 2016.
>
> Guernsey Water *are* the only [*company that charge*](https://www.manxutilities.im/media/1273/manx-utilities-cromwall-energy-report-review-of-charging-regimes_final.pdf) customers with cesspits/septic tanks … Manx Utilities

Note that *company* as plural also goes for the proper names of businesses. American English almost never does this.

This does not mean that an American does not occasionally use a plural verb with *company*:

> With high ceilings and hundreds of thousands of books neatly tucked away into boxes, the facility itself is privately owned and operated by the Clancy-Cullen Moving and Storage [_Company, who charge](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=vcmisc20110331-01.2.17&txq=%22company+who+charge%22) as much as $13 to transport each volume. — *Miscellany News* (Vassar College), 144/18, 24 March 2011.

Since the company name consists of two surnames, the writer was likely led to use a plural verb as well as the personal *who*: Clancy and Cullen are the ones charging the $13. Otherwise, North Americans generally go for the singular, even with *who*:

> We have found another [*company who charges*](http://technology-tax-credits.com/faq/we-have-found-another-company-who-charges-less-for-their-services/) less for their services. — Technology Initiatives Group Ltd. (St. Catherines ON)
>
> There is no question that you will get out of debt cheaper with a debt settlement [*company who charges*](https://tridentdebtsolutions.com/best-debt-settlement-company/) a percentage of savings vs. a percentage of total debt. — Trident Debt Solutions, Boulder/Denver CO.

So whether you use a plural verb depends mostly on which standard of English you wish to follow.